# relative import of an svg in an image tag angular 4

Tags: html, angular, svg

I have an angular 4 app I am trying to import an SVG file into an html file inside an image tag

i.e

```
<img src="../app/scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg">
```

the path to the html file:

```
suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables-app/src/app/browsevenues/venuelist/venuelist.component.html
```

the path to the svg file:

```
/app/scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg
```

I have tried

```
 /app/scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg
./app/scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg
../app/scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg
```

is there something I am missing in importing SVG files as images. This seemed to be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Do you have a `<base href="/">` in `<head>`? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I have imported svg files in my Angular 4 application without doing anything special.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes I do in my index.html file

Comment: And any error message?

Comment: nope no error message

Comment: You're off by one level. `<img src="../../scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg">`

Comment: nice @Z.Bagley thank you. I am still kinda fuzy on file imports. Do you care to share a resource?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your images in src/assets/scalableVectorGraphics/... and then :

**HTML**

```
<img src="assets/scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg">
```

If you need to put in stylesheet as background image:

**CSS**:

```
background-image:  url(/assets/scalableVectorGraphics/landingpage/twitter.svg)
```

Comment: Im guessing assets is a file for angular to work with images and other static files much like styles.css is gobal css?

Comment: 'assets' is a folder name by convention. It's path is more important to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

After none of the responses from stack & different websites worked, for me ::before has done the job:

```
 div::before {
  content: url('../assets/images/Office\ Health\ Logo.svg');
 }
```