# Some asset Images are not showing in Ionic app

Tags: html, angular, typescript, npm, ionic4

I am developing ionic 4 app for both android and Ios, I have images with different format like svg and png format. But, In slide menu only svg format images are showing,

```
    public appPages = [
    {
      title: "Alarm Home",
      url: "/home",
      icon: "home.svg"
    },
    {
      title: "Alarm List",
      url: "/totalalarms",
      icon: "list.png"
    },
    {
      title: "My Notifications",
      url: "/notification",
      icon: "bell.png"
    },
    {
      title: "About",
      url: "/about",
      icon: "info.png"
    }
  ];
```

and in Html

```
  <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" (click)='selectedSlideOption(p.url)'>
    <ion-icon slot="start" src="./assets/img/{{p.icon}}"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>
      {{p.title}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: one. use `src="assets/.../myimage.png"`  two. make sure you restart `ng serve` after adding a new file to the assets folder or it simply won't serve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
<img [src]="/assets/img/{{p.icon}}" style="width: 20px" />
```

or

```
<ion-img [src]="/assets/img/{{p.icon}}" style="width: 20px"></ion-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced this issue and this can be done using path like `assets/images/image_name`

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: but It showing svg format images which are in same folder

Comment: Hope this will be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041434/relative-import-of-an-svg-in-an-image-tag-angular-4)